# Indexing in lucene

Tags: zend-framework, optimization

I have requirement like develop search bar which performs searching operation against database tables data.
So I started using the Zend_lucene,
Here problem is ,In My project ,every user has their realated data if he seraches ,the search  has to be done done only related to data created by him so My thought is for every user try to create a seperate index based on their data.

eg user data1 data2
   x     1     2
   y     2     4

if x is logged ,seach for 2 so he should get  2 of his only as results dispalyed,not the 2 of y

so I tried to do index for every user but i know it is wrost thing

please guide me correct in this and provide some good reference for doing indexing and making the search queries

I look forward to your precious answers

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer,this is good.I would like maintain isolation for every user i can achieve this by passing query with user_id so the searching can be done and values retrieved related to particular user_id only instead maintain a separate index for every user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case you can either create a single index or you can create multiple indexes as well. It depends on the size of data you're going to store.

Might be you're knowing that there is some limitations over the size of index. There is `2GB` file size limit of some 32-bit operating systems.

If you have more data for a particular user then i would suggest you to go with individual indexes. And you can create unique index names for each of the user based on their `user_id/username`. Also if you will have individual indexes then each user will be able to see their own data only because for a particular user you will be searching in a particular index.

Apart from **[Zend Lucene](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.search.lucene.html)** doc, a very good and basic level of tutorial is given **[here](http://www.phpbuilder.com/columns/php-lucene/Jason_Gilmore07062011.php3)**